# How can I use Selenium python with website? Now it's blocked by website

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I try to make a script witch will parse website bet365.com. But this website is block selenium and the page is not opening. I have a code:

```
options = Options()
ua = UserAgent()
userAgent = ua.random
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument(f'user-agent={userAgent}')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
driver.get('https://www.bet365.com/')
```

and it doesn't work. can someone help with this?

it just opens browser and do nothing. For other websites it's work correct
this is screenshot[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wc5pd.png

Comment: Hi Andrii! I recommend you to provide the error you are getting or more details.

Comment: How many times have you connected to the site?  Perhaps you are blocked because they don't like being spammed.

Comment: There is no any errors, browser is opens but the site doesn't load. No it is not spam, because I can't connect to website firstly.

Comment: try it, but it don't work to me. May be because I use ubuntu? I don't have webdriver.exe